# How to use a local variable as a dataSource for a tableView in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I have a UITableViewController :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainClass.h"
@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) MainClass *mainClass;
@end
```

And a class that i want to use as a data source for the table view:

```
@interface Domain : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

-(id) initWithName: (NSString*)name;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* list;

@end
```

When i want to simply test if it's working i create a local domain and i add some documents in it:

```
Domain* domain = [[Domain alloc] init];
Document* document1 = [[Document alloc]initWithName:@"test1"];
[domain.list addObject:document1];
```

And then i declare the domain as a data source ( i overrides the two required methods) :

```
self.tableView.dataSource = domain;
```

Unfortunately, this cause a Bad access exception.
I guess it's because the local variables are released too soon.
I'm guessing this because when i declare both domain and document as property, it works just fine.
Can anyone explain me the reason of this too soon release and how to avoid it?

Comment: can you give the exact error message?

Comment: Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 address=0x0)
Or something really close i can't exactly recall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create strong reference to domain, for example:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Domain* domain;
```

And change allocation of your domain object to:

```
self.domain = [[Domain alloc] init];
Document* document1 = [[Document alloc]initWithName:@"test1"];
[self.domain.list addObject:document1];
```

and after that:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self.domain;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
That's what i'm doing right now since it's not working else way.
But it's really impossible to use local variables for this purpose?
Because it's just for testing so it won't be reused elsewhere.

Comment: you cannot use local variables, since their reference to the object disappears at the end of the scope. possibly you could use the associated reference API, but I'd strongly advice against it for this use case, using properties is the standard way of doing this.

Comment: You can add the property declaration to the class extension so it won't be visible out of the class. You can add ivar, like that @implementation MainViewController{Domain* domain;} and after that you can access it like: domain, without the self keyword.

Answer (score 2):

'dataSource' is a weak property, so you must keep another reference to the object for it not to be released.

Therefore defining a property on the view controller is really the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!
I'm doing it right now so i will keep doing that!